# .env not being loaded when run from CLI but is when run from VSCode

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've finished up writing an application in Python, which is working *fine* when running from VSCode, however, when trying to run from the terminal, it doesn't start.

The error I get is:

```
    SQLConnString = 'Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=' + SQLServer+ ';Database=' + SQLDatabase + ';UID='+ SQLLogin +';PWD=' + SQLPassword
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
```

This is obviously quite clear, it's stating that, at least, one of those variables (`SQLServer`, `SQLDatabase`, `SQLLogin` or `SQLPassword`) have the value `None`, and so concatenation fails. That much I understand.

What I don't understand, however, is that those variables are defined, and loaded prior:

```py
SQLServer = os.getenv('SQL_SERVER')
SQLDatabase = os.getenv('SQL_DATABASE')
SQLLogin = os.getenv('SQL_LOGIN')
SQLPassword = os.getenv('SQL_PASSWORD')
```

And, like I mentioned, if I'm in VSCode, and run the python file, then the file starts up fine, and works; no errors. So there is *something* that is different from me debugging it in VSCode, and running `python3 ./mypythonfile.py` in bash.

What am I missing here, why is the environment file's value *not* pulled into the variables when I run it from command line, but *are* when I run it from VSCode. That doesn't make sense. Why is the behaviour different; with one non-functional and the other works fine.

Unfortunately searches of things like *"python3 not loading .env file in cli"* lead me to sources that tell me *how* to create/use a `.env` files; I **have** a file, and it *works* but seems to just not in CLI and I don't understand why. Clearly I'm missing something obvious, but when it works in VSCode, I expect that it should work from CLI.

I've tried this on 2 different devices as well, same result. Runs fine in VSCode, but can't be started from Command Line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the answer. I import other files, which also use data from the environment file. In VSCode, when debugging, you *don't* need `load_dotenv()` in the individual files, you *do* however, when running from python3. I assume that is a bug in the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

I've came across this same issue today.
Once I undestood that the problem was related to the root directory the dubugger was set, it was straight forward to fix it:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}", // <- the secret is here
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Just add "cwd" as the ${fileDirName} so you set the root directory as the file directory itself, then all the relative paths are going to be fixed as well.

Rederences:

- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_python
- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue (ran in VSCode, failed when run from the CLI), but I was already using load_dotenv(). The root cause of my issue was that my python file that ran the load_dotenv() was in a subfolder under the main folder where the .env file was located. So, the solution was to pass in the path to the .env file to load_dotenv, simply `load_dotenv(path_to_env_file)`. This works in both VSCode and from the CLI.

I'm not exactly sure what goes on behind the scenes in VSCode that enables it to avoid this issue.