# Why I can't access my environment variable from .env file in vscode python?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, environment-variables, dotenv

**What I am trying to do?**
I am trying to access my environment variable from the .env file and print its value in the terminal.

**What is the issue?**
When I run the script in the terminal I keep getting the error `none`

**Some more info:**

I am using Windows 10

The version of dotenv is 0.20.0

I downloaded it using  `python -m pip install python-dotenv`

**The code**

.env file -
`export PRIVATE_KEY = 0xc3c4e4fe27d8e6b06710e713878e4488c034ce346a578fdfa78bb3d335130eec`

The Python file -

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv

 import os

 load_dotenv()

 print(os.getenv("PRIVATE_KEY"))
```

Comment: .env files should only have key-value pairs. Why are you using `export` statements in there? And `export` does not work for Windows anyway. Try putting `PRIVATE_KEY=yourkey` in the .env file and run it.

Comment: try ```from dotenv import dotenv_values``` and then ```env_values = dotenv_values(".env")```  ............do not use ```EXPORT```

Comment: Is that a real private key?

Comment: is that a real private key? if yes, then please don't share your private key like this. You can use an empty string or whatever but don't reveal the real one.

Comment: it's not a real private key but thank you for your concern 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved my issue but it wasn't after removing the "export" in the .env file (I tried with and without it both gave the same results in the terminal), I had to specify the full path of the .env file in the load_dotenv(), apparently I had to specify it but many code samples I saw in forums didn't need to do it I wonder why?

Here is the new code...

The Python code -

[image]

The .env file -

[image]

*by the way it's not a real private key*

At some point before I found the solution I ran the Python script in the terminal and got a random private key (I don't have it pictured sadly), it might had been a key I set in the past but then I checked if I had other .env files in the folder but I had none I also didn't have any environment variables in System Properties > Advanced > Environment Variables on windows so where does dotenv gets the key values by dafault? also After that I reopened vscode and tried again but I got a `none` error...

Comment: Has anyone figured out how to let the .py file automatically detect the .env file in the same directory?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `envfile` node in the `launch.json` file, point to your `.env` file (using an absolute path),.

Then press `F5` to debug the code, or click the green triangle button after selecting the Run and Debug icon on the left.

[image]

Below is a sample of my code along with the output.

**Project structure:**

[image]

**launch.json:**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "envFile": "C:\\WorkSpace\\pyenv\\py.env",

            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true
        }
    ]
}
```

**py.env:**

```
PRIVATE_KEY = 123456789abcdefghijklmn
```

**Test.py:**

```
import os

print(os.getenv("PRIVATE_KEY"))
```

**terminal output:**

[image]

**update:**

`dotenv` gets the environment variables in the `.env` file by default.
If you change the `py.env` file name in your project to `.env`. then the code you showed in your question will run successfully without any changes.

[image]

Comment: I've been following number of different instructions, including this one. None of them will have any effect on environment. Based on what should `.env`-file work?

Comment: If you can, it's best to ask a question of your own. Without understanding your specific problem, we may not be able to help you much.

Comment: Problem is in the question. It's the answers that won't work.

Comment: To make it work you need to do two things; 

(1.) Use the VSCode "Open Folder" option to open a directory on your laptop. This directory should have your source code and .env file. Opening a folder will clear your other open tabs in VSCode, (but you can open them again). This action tells VSCode to set {$Workspace} to the folder you just opened.  

(2.) Choose Menu, Code, Preferences, Settings. Use the search to filter with 
 ".env". Find the setting "Python: env file". In there, set the path to your local env file, e.g."${workspaceFolder}/test/config/test.env".

Answer (score 0):

(I posted the same answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77337086/12087525)

I've came across this same issue today.
Once I undestood that the problem was related to the root directory the dubugger was set, it was straight forward to fix it:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}", // <- the secret is here
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Just add "cwd" as the ${fileDirName} so you set the root directory as the file directory itself, then all the relative paths are going to be fixed as well.

Rederences:

- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_python
- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference

Answer (score -1):

If all the solutions don't work, and your .env file still won't work, here is a workaround:

Add the following lines to the top of your main routine (or to conftest.py if you need them for tests).

This code will read your .env file and create your environment variables:

```
# Workaround for .env file not working
temp_res = os.getenv("SOME_VARIABLE", "") # Try to read an env variable
if temp_res == "": # Nope, .env file settings are not present
    # Manually load environment variables
    with open(os.path.expanduser("~/path/on/my/laptop/my_env_file.env")) as env_file:
        for line in env_file:
            lhs = line.split("=")[0]
            rhs = line.split("=")[1]
            os.environ[lhs]=rhs.strip()
```